# Why do we need to delay when sending char to serial port?

Tags: c, kernel

Consider this code [here](https://github.com/kelwin/6.828/blob/master/kern/console.c#L14):

```
// Stupid I/O delay routine necessitated by historical PC design flaws
static void
delay(void)
{
    inb(0x84);
    inb(0x84);
    inb(0x84);
    inb(0x84);
}
```

What is port `0x84`? Why is it a design flaws? `delay()` is used in [serial_putc()](https://github.com/kelwin/6.828/blob/master/kern/console.c#L65) function:

```
static void
serial_putc(int c)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0;
         !(inb(COM1 + COM_LSR) & COM_LSR_TXRDY) && i < 12800;
         i++)
        delay();

    outb(COM1 + COM_TX, c);
}
```

The file is from [lab1 of the course Operating System Engineering from OCW](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-828-operating-system-engineering-fall-2012/labs/lab1.tar.gz).

Comment: The header on the section that code came from (starting line 211 in referenced version) says that it's for Parallel ports, not serial. So is that what you really mean, if so - correct your question.

Comment: I fixed the source file. The above comment about parallel port is not relevant. That comment should be put after the `delay()` function as in [here](https://github.com/kelwin/6.828/blob/master/kern/console.c#L107).

Comment: Well, in the first link you referenced, that delay function was only used when accessing a parallel port... And that `0x84` [seems to put](http://www.embeddedrelated.com/groups/rabbit-semi/show/23105.php) a LPT port in output mode.

Comment: I don't know what the coder meant, but to me the flaw is not the delay, but the `serial_putc`, because `putc` is synchronous, and synchronous imply delay by design. I've already coded for the same serial port design, but with asynchronous calls, and I didn't add any delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The serial port is a piece of hardware with some semantic you have to accept. It usually has a shift register that makes the conversion from parallel to serial data. It can have a holding register for the next byte to send or even a FIFO for more than one byte. That's why you have to poll the line status register (LSR).

There are some hardware revisions out there that doesn't behave correctly. Your code looks like a workaround for a bug in old hardware. It shouldn't be necessary to read the port 0x84 here.

But the delay implementation can't be optimized out when you increase the compiler optimization level since it's accessing the I/O range. Running this code in a up-to-date hardware might be problematic if the run-time performance gives too little delay. You will have to verify that the maximum time that can be waited in the loop is sufficient to shift out one byte by the UART. Keep in mind that this is baudrate-dependend while you code example isn't.

The port 0x84 is used to access the "extra page register" ([Overview](http://www.bime.ntu.edu.tw/~ttlin/course15/download_files/C15_TECH_DOC_14%20PC%20IO%20PORT%20LIST.pdf)). But reading this register should be a noop. Only the read operation itself is important to consume CPU cycles.

Comment: So, `delay()` uses some random instructions to consume CPU cycles and that's about it. Thanks for all the info.